# Jasmine 2.0: Asynchronous test case

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, jasmine-async

I am trying to perform an asynchronous unit test:

```
 it('Async thing', function (done) {
      scope.$on('async-stuff-happened', function (e) {
         console.log(e);
         done();
         expect(e.stuff).toEqual("stuff");
     });
     scope.ayncStuff();
 });
```

I can see in the console the line `console.log(e)` executed, but the test result is :

```
SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS Async thing
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the `done()` call down after the assert statement:

```
it('Async thing', function (done) {
  scope.$on('async-stuff-happened', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    expect(e.stuff).toEqual("stuff");
    done();
  });
  scope.ayncStuff();
});
```